# How to get getDeclaredMethod in Generic type class?(Kotlin Reflection)

Tags: kotlin, reflection

How to get getDeclaredMethod in Generic type class by Kotlin Reflection

i declared generic type class

```kotlin
class ForReflectionTest<T>(val data:T=null) : SuperTester<T>{
    fun init(data2: T?){
    }
}
```

and i want access it by reflection.
this class create so many instances (over 30+, or maximum over 500+)
and every instance has different type of Data.

and this instances managed in `list<ForReflectionTest>`

but when i try `getDeclaredMethod()`, android throw `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.my.test.ForReflectionTest.init [class java.lang.String]`

how can i solve it?

i tried like this (call side)

```kotlin
for(i:ForReflectionTest<*> in instanceList){
    val method: Method = i.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("init", Any::class.java) // Error! NoSuchMethod
    method.invoke(i, null)
}
```

and other try. (data is nullable)

```kotlin
val method: Method = i.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("init", if(i.data != null)i.data::class.java else Unit::class.java)) // Error! NoSuchMethod
```

i create `var i = i:ForReflectionTest<String>()`
and i try like this,
`i.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod(i.data::class.java)`
it occur error NoSuchMothod. but why?
isn't created `init` method has `String` type Parameter in compile time?

**when i remove generic and try like this, is Successful!**

```kotlin
class ForReflectionTest(val data:String?=null) : SuperTester<String>{
    fun init(data2: String?){
    }
}
```

call side

```kotlin
var i = i:ForReflectionTest()
i.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("init", String::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Kotlin reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html) instead of the Java reflection.

Then you can just write:

```
val method = i::class.declaredFunctions.first { it.name == "init" }
method.call(i, null /* or whatever data you want to use as argument */)
```

If you want to call the `init` function with the `data` value of you `i` element, you can just call `method.call(i, i.data)`.